# how to scroll to the center of a LazyRow item?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-layout

The `LazyRow` `LazyListState` has the method `animateScrollToItem` which scrolls to the end of a list item

I want to scroll to the center of the listItem.

I can do that by passing a `scrollOffset` to the `animateScrollToItem`, something like `listItem.width / 2` , but I was not able to figure out the width of the listItem I want to scroll.

The `LazyListState` provides the `val visibleItemsInfo: List<LazyListItemInfo>` list and I can do something like this

```
suspend fun LazyListState.animateScrollEndCenter(index: Int) {
    val itemInfo = this.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == index }
    if (itemInfo != null) {
        val center = this@animateScrollEndCenter.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset / 2
        val itemCenter = itemInfo.offset + itemInfo.size / 2
        this@animateScrollEndCenter.animateScrollBy((itemCenter - center).toFloat())
    } else {
        this@animateScrollEndCenter.animateScrollToItem(index)
    }
}
```

but `visibleItemsInfo` is nullable, so it does not have information about the `listItem.width`, until the listItem is presented on the screen

In the following example, I'm scrolling to the listItem 11

When is on the screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0fk2.gif

When is out of the screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P554i.gif

I want to scroll to the center of the `LazyRow` listItem

Comment: The behavior you need is already presented in `Accompaniet Pager`. Try to check it source code (or mayby use it instead?).


https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/

Comment: hi @Dwane13 , this could work, but this is part of a huge App Main screen, it will be very risky to add something in alpha testing

Comment: Don't worry. Despite being in alpha accompaniest libs are stable and use latest compose version. They are also developed by Google, as far as i remember